# Mean for seat allocation

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

There are a set of kids (let's say 30) asked to sit in a row of seats, leaving at least one empty seat between them until all seats are filled. At the end, how do I calculate mean of the fraction of occupied seats? What will be the input to calculate mean?

Comment: It seems that the number $N$ of seats is given in advance. Define the process by which seats are taken one by one. Only then one can start calculating  expectations.

Comment: Do you mean, when first one is taken, it will be 1/n and the next one, 2/(n-2)...?